# Where does the NOT LOCAL AFTER JOURNAL get stored in the Teradata Catalog tables

Tags: teradata, catalog, journal

When I run this below query,

```
CREATE SET TABLE "DBC1"."NotLocalTable",FALLBACK, BEFORE JOURNAL , NOT LOCAL AFTER JOURNAL , CHECKSUM = LOW  (
    "Column1" CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
    "Column2" CHARACTER(5)
);
```

I see the catalog Journal column contains a value **SS**, which indicates both the before and after journals are **Single** But actually I have run **NOT LOCAL** for AFTER JOURNAL. Since am not sure why in catalog tables the value is shown as **S** (SINGLE AFTER JOURNAL). Meanwhile I checked the Teradata documentation, where it does not show any support/How it gets stored in the Catatlog table, for NOT LOCAL AFTER JOURNAL.

The JournalFlag Column contains only the below values,

---

### Value     |     Description          |

N        -->      No journal (default)

S        -->      Single journal

D        -->      Dual journal

L        -->      Local AFTER journal

Since I could execute the query without any errors, I see the Teradata accepts NOT LOCAL AFTER JOURNAL, but where does it get stored in the catalog tables ? any Idea ?

Regards,

Ravi

Answer (score 2):

A `NOT LOCAL AFTER` journal is exactly the same as `AFTER`, so it's `S`.

When you define `AFTER JOURNAL` and then do a SHOW TABLE you will read `NOT LOCAL AFTER JOURNAL`